# How to render joomla.searchtools filters in the front end of a custom component?

Tags: joomla-3.x, front-end, jlayout

I'm trying to render the joomla.searchtools in the front end of a custom component.

I extended JModelList for my model, and I can see the list in the front end.
Pagination works well.

But when in my template I add:

```
    echo JLayoutHelper::render('joomla.searchtools.default',
        array('view' => $this)
    );
```

I get an error message like this:

> 0 Call to a member function getGroup() on null

If I change the code above with:

```
<div class="btn-wrapper input-append">
    <input type="text" name="filter[search]" id="filter_search" value="" class="js-stools-search-string" placeholder="Search">
    <button type="submit" class="btn hasTooltip" title="" aria-label="Search" data-original-title="Search">
        <span class="icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    </button>
</div>
```

The search filter shows and works well.

What have I forgotten?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had forgotten two lines in the view:

```
$this->filterForm    = $this->get('FilterForm');
$this->activeFilters = $this->get('ActiveFilters');
```

If someone is interested, [here](https://github.com/framontb/JoomlaBasicExtensions) you can find a component example (com_buscador_site) that uses Joomla searchtools in Front End.